# Does those ExitPolicy make my relay a Tor non-exit relay?

Tags: relays, configuration

I just set up a non-exit relay and it seems to work. I just want to make sure that I really have a non-exit relay. In the torrc file I set the option ExitPolicy to `reject *:*`.

Does this make a non-exit relay? I thought so, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proper configuration line for a non-exit relay is

```
ExitPolicy reject *:*
```

Since that's what you're using, you should be fine.

Comment: I wrote *.*, but the * disappeared. But thanx!

Comment: Fixed both, your question and the answer then :)

Answer (score 5):

You can look up your own relay on [Atlas](https://atlas.torproject.org/) and check your Exit Policy and flags.

And yes, rejecting everything, like you do, makes you a non-exit.